# What is the difference between ordered and unordered n-tuple?

Tags: linear-algebra

From browsing the internet so far I've came to the conclusion that an ordered tuple is something in which there is no repettion of the elments
Eg: An ordered 4-tuple is (1,2,3,4) or (5,3,1,7) i.e. no elements are repeated

But an unordered 4-tuple is something like this (1,2,2,3) or (7,1,4,1)

Is this a valid difference between an ordered and an unordered tuple? If yes then are there any other differences??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know what an ordered pair is? Generalize this notion.

Comment: No i don't can you elaborate?

Comment: Do you know what a Cartesian product is?

Comment: ya i do know cartesian product. Someone just posted an answer can you tell if that is correct?

Comment: In general, then, does $A\times B = B\times A$?

Comment: @crash no they are not equal. I have got my answer thanks for helping

Comment: If you have got your answer and you are satisfied with it, then you should accept the answer given by the answerer. This shows appreciation to the answerer, and it lets others know that your question has been effectively solved (at least to your satisfaction).

Comment: @crash i have to wait 15 minutes to approve an answer.

Comment: Just to clarify what I meant--accept the answer that was *most* helpful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the Cartesian product to clarify things a little bit.

The Cartesian product of two sets $A$ and $B$ is defined to be the set of all **ordered pairs** $(a,b)$ where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. The Cartesian product is often written as
$$
A\times B = \{(a,b)\mid a\in A\space\text{and}\space b\in B\}.
$$
Thus, consider the Cartesian product when $A=\{1\}$ and $B=\{2\}$. We get $A\times B=\{(1,2)\}$. What about $B\times A$? We get $\{(2,1)\}$. For Cartesian products, $\{(1,2)\}\neq \{(2,1)\}$ because the pairs are **ordered**. $\color{red}{\text{The manner in which the entries appear matters}}$, as Robert Israel pointed out.

The Cartesian product is concerned with $2$-tuples. The same reasoning may be applied to any $n$-tuple.

Comment: I preferred the answer that you used earlier, can you change it?

Comment: @TripleS OK. I assume you mean *this* answer that you just accepted--glad you found it helpful. Robert's answer contains some more information that you may want to follow up on to solidify the concept.

Comment: yup this one thanks. And yes Robert's answer was helpful too, that's why I gave him a thank you note and I'll certainly vote him up from my other account, but I needed some example so I accepted this answer.

Answer (score 9):

No, that's completely wrong.  Whether ordered or unordered, there may or may not be repetitions.  The correct distinction is that in an ordered tuple the order counts, and in an unordered tuple it doesn't.  So $(1,2,2,3)$ and $(2,1,2,3)$ are different as ordered $4$-tuples, but they are the same as unordered $4$-tuples.

Comment: If they are unordered and repetitions are allowed, it might be clearer to say *[multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset)*