# Sequences which differ only in element order

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

The elements of a set have no order whereas the elements of a sequence have an order. Is there a name for the equivalence relation between sequences which differ only in the order of their elements, e.g. 1, 2, 1, 3 and 2, 1, 1, 3?

**Edit 1**: The background is that I'm reading my old book on combinatorics again where it goes through selection with or without repetition and ordering. I'm trying to reformulate the problem descriptions in terms of $k$-tuples of a set of $n$ elements:

1. The number of k-tuples is $n^k$.
2. The number of k-tuples with distinct elements is $P(n, k)$.
3. The number of equivalence classes of the set of k-tuples defined by $xRy$ if $x$ differs from $y$ only in the element order is $C(n + k - 1, k)$.
4. The number of subsets of $k$ elements is $C(n, k)$.

My question is basically how point three can be more succinctly formulated.

**Edit 2**: Jean-Armand Moroni mentioned multisets in the comments so then we can reformulate point three as "The number of multisets of cardinality $k$ is $C(n + k - 1, k)$." I'm still curious though if there is a name for the equivalence relation.

Comment: Do you only consider finite sequences in a set $X$, i.e. tuples $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$?

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes (to begin with at least).

Answer (score 1):

One could say that the sequences are **rearrangements** of each other, or **permutations** of each other.

One could obtain one sequence by **rearranging**, or **permuting**, the elements of the other sequence.

Below is an excerpt from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem) illustrating the usage.

> In mathematics, the Riemann series theorem, also called the Riemann rearrangement theorem, named after 19th-century German mathematician Bernhard Riemann, says that if an infinite series of real numbers is conditionally convergent, then its terms can be arranged in a permutation so that the new series converges to an arbitrary real number, or diverges. This implies that a series of real numbers is absolutely convergent if and only if it is unconditionally convergent.

Edit: If you want to keep the k-tuple formulation, you can consider saying something like **k-tuples up to reordering**. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1165207/what-is-the-difference-between-ordered-and-unordered-n-tuple) for a discussion of ordered vs unordered $k$-tuples.

Your suggestion of formulating $3.$ as

> The number of multisets of cardinality k is C(n+k−1,k)

seems good.

Comment: There seems to be an interesting relationship between series and rearrangements: the more the rearrangement displaces elements, the more stringent should be the condition on series so that their sum does not change. What are the rearrangements which do not change the sum of any conditionnally convergent series? Exactly those with bounded displacement?

Comment: As far as I understand permutations requires distinct elements but the sequences in my example can contain duplicate elements.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom Permutations of a set require (of course) distinct elements, but permutations of a multiset allow non-distinct elements, cf. Wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni I had forgotten about multisets, thanks! Then we can say that $xRy$ if $x$ and $y$ are permutations of the same multiset, right?

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom Yes, that looks good. Note that the definition of a multiset may or may not allow negative multiplicities. Here you want only positive multiplicities. I don't know which definition of a multiset is the most usual.

Answer (score -2):

They are called [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset). In your case multisets consisting of integers.